# Vulkan Error: cmd buffer submit cant use image because of layout

Tags: vulkan

I've been coding a Vulkan rendering engine for the past few weeks.
My code still continues to execute and I get the desired output, but I am getting an error.

I'm fairly certain that my error is a mistake in my code somewhere. My code is 1000+ lines, so I'm not going to ask anyone to debug it. I guess my question is what typically causes the error I'm getting, and how can I fix it?

I've been pretty closely following this (if this helps anyone): https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/api-without-secrets-introduction-to-vulkan-part-3#_Toc445674490

My code draws the desired triangle from the tutorial, but I get an error for the first 3 frames:

```
VKDBG: ERROR: @[DS]: Cannot submit cmd buffer using image (0x6) [sub-resource: aspectMask 0x1 array layer 0, mip level 0], with layout VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED when first use is VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR.
VKDBG: ERROR: @[DS]: Cannot submit cmd buffer using image (0x7) [sub-resource: aspectMask 0x1 array layer 0, mip level 0], with layout VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED when first use is VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR.
VKDBG: ERROR: @[DS]: Cannot submit cmd buffer using image (0x8) [sub-resource: aspectMask 0x1 array layer 0, mip level 0], with layout VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED when first use is VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR.
```

I suppose I could just ignore this, because I get a desired output and the error doesn't seem to break anything, but I would guess that it's bad practice to leave this unfixed.

Thank you for anyone helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swapchain images, when acquired from the presentation engine, are in a PRESENT_SRC layout. Before we can use an image in a command buffer, we need to transition away from this layout, but using the UNDEFINED as an old layout during transition is also a proper behaviour. Nevertheless, it should also be a proper behaviour to transition away from the PRESENT_SRC layout and the reported error is (probably) a bug in validation layers.

Comment: No, it's not a bug, [swapchain images acquired from the presentation engine are initially in the layout `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0-wsi_extensions/xhtml/vkspec.html#_wsi_swapchain) as defined in the specification.

Answer (score 3):

[From Dustin Graves of LunarG about this exact issue](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-LoaderAndValidationLayers/issues/46):

> This message appears to be generated for a swapchain image that is not being tranitioned from `UNDEFINED` to `PRESENT_SRC_KHR`. Initializing `texture->imageLayout` as `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED` instead of `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR` in `GpuTexture_CreateFromSwapChain` should take care of it.

Comment: Thank you! I had found that before, and looked through it, but I assumed the issue was different because it seemed to deal with loading textures.

Comment: If you look below at the end of the comments thread there is someone who has the identical issue you had, not the primary issue I had linked to, they're all part of a common group of validation layer behaviors.

Answer (score 0):

Right, I thought images acquired from the presentation engine are always in PRESENT_SRC layout, not after the first time they were acquired:

"After a successful return, the image indicated by pImageIndex will still be in the VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR layout if it was previously presented, or in the VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED layout if this is the first time it has been acquired."

So it is safer to always transition away from the UNDEFINED layout.